# How to Running applications automatically when X starts?

Tags: linux, redhat, scripting

for RHEL5 How to run a script or application automatically after starting X server (after loading level 5)?

Answer (score 1):

For KDE you can put a symbolic link to an executable in the directory home/username/.kde/autostart

For GNOME just go to `system -> preferences -> startup applications`

Comment: Actually this will be executed after login not after starting X server

Comment: @ghm1014 Okay should try and restate your question then since you ask "after starting X Server"